# Multiply 2-D array

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I am fairly new to C++ programming language. Currently, what I am trying to accomplish is getting a short* input from MATLAB, creating its transpose and multiplying. I am having problems when I try to multiply. I am getting h_raw from MATLAB and doing some computation to get sh_data. This looks correct. Next, I am creating a transpose dst which is also correct. Finding the covariance matrix is giving me troubles. This covariance matrix should be MATALB equivalent to cov_matrix=sh_data * sh_data';  Any help is appreciated!

```
for (int numEl = 0; numEl < elements; numEl++) {
    int shift_idx = tof[1 + (1 * pix_x * numEl)];
    for (int sdex = 0; sdex < shift_idx; sdex++) {
            for (int p = 0; p < nrows; p++) {
                sh_data[p + (numEl*nrows)] = h_raw[(p + sdex) + (numEl*nrows)];
            }

    }
}

// finding the transpose
for (int n = 0; n < nrows*ncols; n++) {
    int i = n / ncols;
    int j = n % ncols;
    dst[n] = sh_data[nrows*j + i];
}

// calculating the covariance matrix

for (int nel = 0; nel < elements; nel++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < nrows; k++) {
            cov_matrix[(nel*elements)+nel] += dst[(k*elements)+nel] * sh_data[k+(nel*nrows)];

    }
}
```

Comment: You're going for a transpose and a normal matrix multiplication, but actually if you're writing it from scratch it's easier to implement multiply-by-transpose as a single operation, would you accept an answer based on that?

Comment: yeah sure! i would be very curious to know if there is an easier way. like i said i am very new to C++ so any help would be very appreciated.